# arduino esp8266 wifiserver client request timeout

Tags: php, arduino, timeout, webserver, esp8266

I'm trying to do an GET request from a PHP script to an esp8266 Wifiserver to turn a LED ON or OFF and return a JSON-object like this:`{led:'off'}` of `{led:'on'}` depending on the state of the LED.

The URL looks something like this:`http://[IP-NUMBER]/LED=ON&access_token=x`

When I make a request to the URL via the browser everything is working fine except the browser loading indicator shows an infinite loading state. (I do get the JSON-object back and de LED is turning ON or OFF).

So also when I try to call `$result = file_get_contents($url);` in a PHP script, the `file_get_contents` returns a connection timeout error after a while. The same thing is happening when performing a PHP curl get request.

So the problem is that every GET request to the esp8266 never seems to end and is therefore loading infinitely.

Does somebody know why a GET request to the esp8266 webserver is resolving in a timeout?

This is the code on the esp8266:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "xx";
const char* password = "xx";

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);


  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  client.flush();

  // Match the request
  if (request.indexOf("&access_token=x") != -1) {


    int value = LOW;
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1) {
      value = HIGH;
      Serial.print('1');
    } 
    if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1){
      value = LOW;
      Serial.print('0');
    }

    // Return the response
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    client.println(""); //closing header

    client.print("{led:'");

    if(value == HIGH) {
      client.print("on");  
    } else {
      client.print("off");
    }
    client.println("'}");
  } else {
    client.println("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println(""); //closing header
    client.println("No Access"); 
  }
  client.stop();
  delay(1);
}
```

p.s. the esp8266 is sending a `1` or a `0` through the Serial to an arduino which is handeling the LED turning ON or OFF.

---- edit ----

I added a `Content-Length` attribute to the header which stopped the infinite loading state when targeting the URL via a webbrowser, but a `file_get_contents($url);` request or a PHP curl request stil resolves in a timeout.

---- edit2 ----

I replaced the PHP curl request with a Javascript AJAX request and set a CORS allowed header on the esp8266 webserver which seems to work pretty good!

But still don't know why the PHP requests are resulting in a timeout, so the problem is solved but the question remains unanswered.

Comment: Maybe because of the missing `Content-Length` header?

Comment: i'll give it a try!

Comment: Ok nice! That worked partially, the page is not infinite loading anymore, but I still get an `Connection timed` error when running `file_get_contents($url)`.

Comment: I'll try a curl GET request...

Comment: solved by replacing the PHP curl request with a javascript AJAX request with CORS allowed header set on the esp8266 webserver, so that works now, but stil don't know why the PHP curl request was getting a constant timeout 8)